# data/item inside my combo box keeps multiplying whenever i click on it

Tags: vb.net

after adding items to the combo box whenever I run it and click on the combobox the data inside the box just multiply itself, anyhelp pls … This is my code

```
 Private Sub productcombobox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles productcombobox.Click

        productcombobox.Items.Add("Manage Product")
        productcombobox.Items.Add("Add Product")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to repopulate the control every time it's clicked in the first place? This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add the clear() methods before you add the data into the combo box

```
Private Sub productcombobox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles productcombobox.Click
        productcombobox.Clear()
        productcombobox.Items.Add("Manage Product")
        productcombobox.Items.Add("Add Product")
    End Sub
```

this is your code so just add the Clear() method before other things ..

Comment: This will prevent the symptom but it doesn't seem like a good solution. I have to wonder why you would want to remove all items and then repopulate the list with the same data again every time the control is clicked. It seems like this is a solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: At the very least, just check whether there are items and don't add any if there are. Clearing and repopulating is pointless at best.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    productcombobox.Items.Add("Manage Product")
    productcombobox.Items.Add("Add Product")
End Sub
```

No discussion necessary considering the comments already posted.

Comment: Why is there need to populate items whenever a combobox is clicked? This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @preciousbetine :-) Thanks!